# jquery get generated id with the same class

Tags: jquery

Here is my code.

```
//generate a id
$(".slide_img_a").each(function(){
 $(this).attr("id","img"+(Math.round(Math.random()*100)))
});

// get id   
var img_id = $(".slide_img_a").attr("id");

// alert the id  
$(".slide_img_a img").hover(function(){
 alert(img_id);
});
```

The problem of this is I have a 5 images with the same class and random id. When I hover the image, the result is he can only alert the id of first image. I wanted to do is when I hover them they will alert thier own id's

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicate `id` s and your method will create duplicate `id` s sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` inside the event handler and find what you want that way, like this:

```
$(".slide_img_a img").hover(function(){
  alert($(this).closest(".slide_img_a").attr("id"));
});
```

This takes the image you hovered at the time of hover then uses [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to go up to the `.slide_img_a` container, and *that* is the element we're pulling the ID from.

---

For pre-1.3 versions of jQuery (since we know the `<a>` doesn't have the class) you can do this:

```
$(".slide_img_a img").hover(function(){
  alert($(this).parents(".slide_img_a:first").attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: $(".slide_img_a").closest is not a function

Comment: @Jordan - you can use .parents('.slide_img_a:first') instread for older versions of jquery.